# Add a row with name dynamically to Matlab uitable

Tags: matlab

I have a class like this. I want to add and remove rows dynamically as needed. The `AddRow` method doesn't work. Not sure how to do it.

Using the code below, I can see that a data row is being added, but the name is not being displayed. Am I doing this wrong, or is it possible that the name is there but the column is not visible?

```
classdef BidAskDisplay < handle
    properties
        f
        ut
        myhandles
    end

    methods     
        function self = BidAskDisplay(name, colNames) 
           self.CreateBidAskDisplay(name, colNames);
        end

        function CreateBidAskDisplay(self, name, colNames)
            % Example quote display
            % Copyright 2015 The MathWorks, Inc.

            self.f = figure; 
            self.f.Name = name;   

            self.ut = uitable(self.f, 'ColumnName', colNames, 'RowName',[]);
            self.ut.Units = 'normalized';
            self.ut.ColumnWidth = {150};
            self.ut.Position(3) = self.ut.Extent(3);
            self.ut.Position(4) = 0.9;
            self.ut.Data = repmat({'NaN'},0 ,3);

            self.myhandles = guidata(self.ut); 
        end

        function AddRow(self, rowName)            
            data = get(self.myhandles, 'Data');            
            newRowdata = cat(1, data, cell(1, size(data, 2)));            
            set(self.ut, 'Data', newRowdata)

            k = size(data, 1) + 1; % Which row number does the new row get
            rnames = get(self.myhandles, 'RowName');
            rnames{k, 1} = rowName;

            set(self.myhandles, 'RowName', rnames);          
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: make your class a `handle` class, else you must call something like `obj = obj.AddRow` for the value class

Comment: Thanks I made that change. If you don't mind, I am very new to matlab. Not sure how to actually add a new row?

Answer (score 0):

According to your initialization `self.ut.Data = repmat({'NaN'},0 ,3);`, your table has 3 columns. To add new row, you have to change your `table.Data`, not the `RowNames`. So your function `AddRow` should be similar to following example:

```
function AddRow(self, new_row_data)
    % new_row_data must be a cell of size 1x3
    % e.g. new_row_data = {'a1', 'b2', 'c3'}
    self.ut.Data = [self.ut.Data; new_row_data];
end
```